# How to compile Mellanox libvma on gentoo?

Tags: c++, linux, gentoo, low-latency, hft

I am trying to build Mellanox's high speed network library libvma on gentoo

http://code.google.com/p/libvma/

However I keep on getting this error

```
In file included from ../../src/vma/util/sys_vars.h:24:0,
from ../../src/vma/util/utils.h:22,
from vlogger.cpp:25:
../../src/vma/util/verbs_extra.h: In function 'void ibv_flow_spec_ib_set_by_dst_gid(vma_ibv_flow_spec_ib*, uint8_t*)':
../../src/vma/util/verbs_extra.h:151:4: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'vma_ibv_flow_spec_ib {aka struct ibv_flow_spec_ib}'
../../src/vma/util/verbs_extra.h:110:16: error: forward declaration of 'vma_ibv_flow_spec_ib {aka struct ibv_flow_spec_ib}'
../../src/vma/util/verbs_extra.h:151:13: error: 'IBV_FLOW_SPEC_IB' was not declared in this scope*
```

It appears that structs IBV_FLOW* should have been declared in /usr/include/infiniband/ verbs.H file. However they appear to be missing there. Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try to compile libvma on gentoo,
but you will need to install MLNX_OFED or the latest libibverbs in order to get flow-steering capabilites for user-space infiniband verbs.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot. Only if you patch kernel with kernel stuff from mlnx_ofed srpms.